# How to split strings using two delimiter in Oracle 11g regexp_substr functions

Tags: regex, oracle11gr2, regexp-substr

I have doubt to split a string using the delimiter.

First split based on , delimiter select those splitted strings should split based on - delimiter

My original string: `UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,`
Expected output:

```
UMC12I
CSM3
VQ
```

Each value comes as row value

I tried the option

```
WITH fab_sites AS (
  SELECT trim(regexp_substr('UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) fab_site
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,', '[^,]+')+1
)
SELECT fab_site FROM   fab_sites WHERE fab_site IS NOT NULL
```

-- splitted based on , delimiter

Output is:

```
UMC12I-1234
CSM3-123
VQ
```

how can I get my expected output? (need to split again - delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the "words" before the `-` with the `regexp_substr` using

```
([^,-]+)(-[^,-]+)?
```

The pattern will match and *capture* into Group 1 one or more chars other than `,` and `-`, then will match an optional sequence of `-` and 1+ chars other than `,`and `-`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Stbwxt/1).

Use this `regex_substr` line instead of yours with the above regex:

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr('UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,', '([^,-]+)(-[^,-]+)?', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)) fab_site
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/QBE60576)

Comment: May your second link has a problem: **online demo**

Comment: @k-five: Typing on a snail-laptop usually results in such "typos". It should be http://rextester.com/QBE60576.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this query:

```
WITH fab_sites AS (
      SELECT TRIM(',' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR('UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,', '(^|,)[^,-]+', 1, LEVEL)) fab_site
        FROM dual
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('UMC12I-1234,CSM3-123,VQ,', '(^|,)[^,-]+')
)
SELECT fab_site
  FROM fab_sites;
```

We start by matching any substring that starts either with the start of the whole string `^` or with a comma `,`, the delimiter. We then get all the characters that match neither a comma nor a dash `-`. Once we have that substring we trim any leftover commas from it.

P.S. I think the `+1` in the `CONNECT BY` clause is extraneous, as is the `WHERE NOT NULL` in the "outer" query.